# Using in_array to compare MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table set up in MySQL with two columns:

- ID (auto_increment)
- recentlyplayed (VARCHAR, set up like "1 44" or "2 140", etc)

I'm trying to get the mysql data into an array and compare it to something defined outside MySQL. But it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Here is my code:

$whichPlaylist is a 1 character INT, and $num is a 3 character INT.

```
//Note: These values are actually received through file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
$whichPlaylist = "1";
$num = "44";

//Combine playlist number and video number
$joint = $whichPlaylist. "" .$num;


//Insert joint var into Mysql database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO recentlyplayed (numplayed) VALUES('$joint') ");


$query = "SELECT * FROM recentlyplayed";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$stored[] = $row['1'];
}


if (in_array($joint, $stored['1'])){
$reroll = 1;
}

echo $reroll;
```

Even if the same value of $joint is in the MySQL table, $reroll doesn't echo 1. Could this because of extra spacing when inserting the $joint variable? I'm actually getting the $whichPlaylist and $num from a text file that has a new line after the number. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: `$row['1']` and `$stored['1']` are the elements of the respective arrays with key the string value `'1'`.  You probably meant `$row[1]` and `$stored`, but so much else is wrong with your code.  Don't use `ext/mysql`; pass your variables as parameters to prepared statements; name the columns you wish to fetch in your select list, rather than using the `*` wildcard; try to avoid loading your entire resultset into an array if possible (e.g. move some processing into the database where possible, or perform processing on each record whilst fetching); exit loops ASAP.

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and will be marked as deprecated with PHP5.5. Use `PDO_MySQL`, or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Answer (score 0):

Move the While End braces after if statement, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your script:

```
$stored = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $stored[] = $row[1];
}

if (in_array($joint, $stored)){
  $reroll = 1;
}
```

The array is $stored (not $stored['1']).